# Awk commands find and replace string and print every thing after key word

Tags: text-processing, awk

New to Linux commands.. What syntax would I use to find and replace a string with each line starting with "Data Centre:" Address information that is different on every line" but ends with the word Site: and I need to keep the site details that follow..

Example:

```
Input.txt
Data Centre: 23 Mulberry lane, Washington Site: 9067 Green

Expected Output
Site: 9067 Green
```

I've found gsub examples, but gsub is not available on my OS.

Any help appreciated.

Mac

Comment: " gsub is not available on my OS". If you're using non-Ubuntu OS, you should be asking on unix.stackexchange.com. Questions posted here are Ubuntu specific and specific to tools used on Ubuntu

Comment: I remember correctly, I was installed `gawk` (`sudo apt install gawk`) on my Ubuntu 16.04 to have `gsub` available.

Comment: I have 16.04 and gsub works out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use semicolon as field separator, what you want will be in the last field

```
awk -F ':'  '/Site:/ { print "Site: ", $NF }'
```

Comment: Thanks Sergiy, very fast, I have a few other comments after the Status of green, I understand the NF is number of fields, is there away of also displaying these e.g in my simple example above there often Warnings if Amber which might call out a fault. Effectively I need to print anything after the Site: Thanks so much.

Comment: It works, but two extra white spaces are added after `Site:`. Here is with `printf`: `awk -F ':'  '/Site:/ { printf "%s\n","Site:"$NF }' Input.txt`

Comment: @majtx  OK, I can edit an answer, but you need to provide the full structure of the file.  How do warnings look like ?  Do  items after site have constant number of strings, like <integer> <string>, or can it be <integer> <string> <something else> ?

Comment: @pa4080 The two whitespaces are added in the  `"Site:  "` part itself. But yes, `printf` can do just fine there.

Comment: @majtx Also  do `ls -l  /etc/alternatives/awk` so we at least know what type of `awk` you have on your system.

Comment: @majtx, if [this] answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) (by click on the grey tick ✓ left to it) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `sed` solution that uses extended regular expressions `-r` and capture groups `()`->`\1`:

```
sed -r 's/^Data Centre:.*(Site: .*)$/\1/' Input.txt
```

If you want to suppress the output of any other lines that could appear in the file:

```
sed -n -r 's/^Data Centre:.*(Site: .*)$/\1/p' Input.txt
```

Add the option `-i.bak` to do the changes and backup file simultaneously, ot redirect the output to new file.